# Pass list of arguments to a command for each line

Tags: arrays, bash

In a bash script:
I have this list of arguments (or directories in this case):

`Directories=(` 
`/Dir1/` 
`/Dir2/`
`/Dir3/`
`)`
And I want every **item** (or line) of this list, to be **passed as a argument** to a command.
Like this:

`cd /Dir1/`
`cd /Dir2/`
`cd /Dir3/`
(Replace "cd" with any command)

I tried this:
`cd ${Directories[@]}`
But that results in this:
`cd /Dir1/ /Dir2/ /Dir3/`

How I can make the script run the command each time with a new line, until it reaches the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**Update**: In fact, the solution below is *not* suitable for commands meant to alter the *current* shell's environment, such as `cd`. It *is* suitable for commands that invoke *external* utilities.
For commands designed to alter the current shell's environment, see [Balaji Sukumaran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376564/45375).</sup>

`xargs` is the right tool for the job:

```
printf '%s\n' "${Directories[@]}" | xargs -I % <externalUtility> %
```

- `printf '%s\n' "${Directories[@]}"` prints each array element on its own line.
- `xargs -I % <externalUtility> %` invokes external command `<externalUtility>` for each input line, passing the line as a *single* argument; `%` is a freely chosen placeholder.

Answer (score 5):

For loop can be used as well

```
#!/bin/bash
Directories=( /dir1 /dir2 /dir3)
for dir in "${Directories[@]}"
do
  cd "${dir}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 ! Added it